# Passing variable to bootstrap modal in MVC3

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc-3, twitter-bootstrap

Code in partial view:

```
//modal
<div id="chartModal" class="modal hide fade">
    <div class="modal-body">
        <center><p> Test </p>

        <input type="text" name="bookId" id="bookId" value=""/>

        <button class="btn" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true"> Cancel</button>
        </center>  
    </div>
</div>

//link
<a data-toggle="modal" data-id="ISBN-001122" title="Add this item" 
    class="open-AddBookDialog btn btn-primary" href="#chartModal">test</a>

//JS
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).on("click", ".open-AddBookDialog", function () {
        var myBookId = $(this).data('id');
        $(".modal-body #bookId").val(myBookId);
        //$('#chartModal').modal('show');
    });
</script>
```

My question is I am trying to pass a string to the modal (Eventually this will be dynamic data containing the variable @ViewBag.somestring). With the string also it does NOT work - the modal appears when clicked on but the textbox does not contain the id which is: "ISBN-001122". I am using jquery-1.7.1 and Bootstrap v2.3.2.

Comment: Did you try `<input type="text" name="bookId" id="bookId" value="@ViewBag.somestring"/>`

Comment: PSL I cannot do that as I have switch statement and several links depending on user input so I cannot simply insert the value directly into the textbox

Comment: What do you mean by `My question is I am trying to pass a string to the modal (Eventually this will be dynamic data containing the variable @ViewBag.somestring).` ?

Comment: I mean: <a data-toggle="modal" data-id='@Html.Raw(ViewBag.Mydata)'... Currently the string is there just for testing. And the Viewbag.Mydata will change depending on user selection hence cannot put into textbox

Comment: In that case you may want to update the data-id of the anchor based on the user selection. If you get the data from the server based on user sleection then you can either do a partial view rendering or update using an ajax call.

Comment: PSL can you give an example of ajax on opening the bootstrap modal with the variable parameter. thanks

Comment: Sure so which action gives you the id? I mean do you have an action that gives you this id? Instead of using viewbag you can have the ajax return the id. Probably you can update the data-id of the anchor while user changes selection as well.